# Searching for pointer i where A[i]=i

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search

Given a sorted array of distinct integers A[1, . . . , n], you want to find out whether there is an
index i for which A[i] = i. Give a divide-and-conquer algorithm that runs in time O(log n).

What i have come up with so far is a modified binary search which will throw away the right half of the array depending the check on the element we have as pivot in binary search at the moment.

```
modifiedBinSearch(a[1],a[n]){

int i = a.length/2;

if(a[i]==i) return i;

if(i>a[i]) return ModifiedBinSearch(a[1],a[i]);

else return ModifiedBinSearch(a[i], a[n]);

}
```

Does this algorithm run in **O(log n)** time? And if not, what should i do in order to make it run in **O(log n)**?

Comment: You pseudo code(or code?) looks strange. What does `a[1], a[n]` mean(do you really pass indices or what)?

Comment: Your analysis is correct, your pseudo code is weird, and it seems it is also missing a stop clause for failure to find such value.

Comment: A nice brain-teaser but it depends heavily on whether duplicate and/or negative values are allowed. The answer that you accepted barely relates to the problem.

Comment: @HenkHolterman **distinct** means no duplicates and negative numbers doesn't prevent it to work. The real problem is the termination condition when there is no index to be found...

Comment: @HenkHolterman If there's a negative number at index `i` in the list, you can't know anything about the numbers in indexes greater than `i`, so I think it's still `O(logn)`. I could easily be missing something though.

Comment: @HenkHolterman consider a modified array where you substracted its index from every value. Then basically the pseudo code is a binary-search for the value `0`. It remains to prove this modified array is sorted. The fact numbers are distinct gives you this condition. Because to maintain the ascending order and the distinctness you must have `a[i+1] >= a[i]+1`, This implies that: `a[i+1]-(i+1) >= a[i]-i`. And by recursion you get the modified array is sorted. And the binary search works even for negative values :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Hmm, I don't see which (assumed) conditions. Could you elaborate please ?

Comment: @mariovergo - what range can the values have? It matters a lot if negative values are allowed or not. So can `a[i] < 0` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your alghoritm does not work, `int i = a.length/2;` this has always the same value, the size of array `a` is not changed.

You do need to remember at least two variables and array. The two variables are "min" and "max" to know the boundaries of array you are recursive binary searching for.

Think about it as listing in dictionary.

For example it has 1024 pages, you are looking for word "berry".

You open it on page 512 and you find "mom", therefore it must be between 0 - 512.

So you look to 256 and you find "alhocol" -> it must be between 256 - 512

etc.

These two values are that min and max and you have to pass them as parameters in your recursive method.

Comment: Sure it works (or at least does not fail for this reason), this is a pseudo code, and not a specific language that you are probably referring to, and array here is a dynamic array (that you can modify to trim upper half and downer half in O(1)).

Answer (score 2):

I apologize in advance for the ridiculous pseudocode. Technically your algorithm runs in `O(logn)` time because half the list is cut off each time (divide by 2 each time, so we get log base 2). However, as libik points out, `a.length` is always the same, so you're not getting anywhere. You need to pass the indices as parameters.

```js
func(a, lo, hi)
    len = hi - lo + 1
    mid = len / 2 + lo
    switch len, a[mid] > mid
        case 1, _: a[lo] = lo ? lo : -1
        case _, t: func(a, lo, mid - 1)
        case _, _: func(a, mid, hi)

func(arr, 0, arr.length - 1)
```

Comment: This too implements a normal binary search. But you have a moving/unknown target with a relation to the position...

Comment: Yeah, it's a binary search. Can you elaborate on your second sentence? @HenkHolterman

Answer (score 0):

If your pseudo code actually means that we pass an array to a function and we can obtain its subarray in `O(1)` time, then the time complexity is indeed `O(log n)` because the size of the array gets(approximatly) twice smaller after each step.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define `A` to be the input array and `N` be the length of this array.

You first need to remark that the array is **sorted** and the integers are **distinct**. This implies that given two indices `(i, j)` where `i < j`, then `A[i]+1 <= A[j]`. In turn this implies that `A[i]-i <= A[i+1]-(i+1)`.

From this remark you can conclude, by using recursion, that the array `B` defined as:

```
For i in (0..N-1) B[i] = A[i]-i
```

Is also a sorted array.

Your pseudo-code is simply a binary-search to find if there is a `0` in `B`. The index of this value is the index you want to find.

Binary-search has got a complexity of `O[log(n)]`.

**Notes:** *why do I say the pseudocode is a binary-search for the value 0 ?*

Just replace the conditions:

- `a[i] == i`, with: `a[i]-i == 0`
- `i > a[i]`, with: `a[i]-i < 0`

**Notes 2**

The pseudocode doesn't handle the case where the value is absent.